# Receiver app - handle permission for intent filter URI

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, intentfilter, android-contentresolver

I'm so confused with the whole Fileprovider thing Android has. All day I spend watching videos and looking at other posts... I hope somebody can quickly help me.

I have an app that processes images/PDF etc... and uploads them to a server. For this I implemented an intent filter on my entry activity.

```
   <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
```

That activity gets the intent, but sends its data to another activity.

```
   (intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra<Parcelable>(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM) as? ArrayList<Uri>)?.let {
        activity.startActivity(MainActivity.newInstance(activity, it))
    }
```

and

```
 public static Intent newInstance(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull ArrayList<Uri> images) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_IMAGES, images);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION|Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    return intent;
}
```

That activity tries to read the Uri with the contentresolver

```
val openInputStream = context.contentResolver?.openInputStream(originalFileUri)
```

But when doing so it will crash - sometimes...

If I shared a photo from the gallery app it all works fine. If I share a photo from the downloads folder then I get

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadStorageProvider from ProcessRecord{40bd561 8082:APPNAME/u0a749} (pid=8082, uid=10749) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs
```

If I share a photo from whatsapp to my app I get

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.whatsapp.contentprovider.MediaProvider from ProcessRecord{a684e0e 6544:APPNAME/u0a749} (pid=6544, uid=10749) that is not exported from UID 10140
```

I'm clueless why this is...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> That activity gets the intent, but sends its data to another activity.

That's not really ideal.

But, if you have to do it, add `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` (and, if needed, `FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION`) to the `Intent` that you use to start `MainActivity`. Otherwise, `MainActivity` [may not have permission to work with the content](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/10/uri-access-lifetime-shorter-than-you-might-think.html).

Comment: still doesnt work, could you do a sanity check on the piece of code I edited above (I added the flags)

Also, could you pass these flags endlessly to a next intent? Cuz there is a flow where the intent gets passed around to 2 activities before it gets read

Comment: @DennisAnderson: Ah, missed that you were passing these via an `Intent` extra rather than in the "data" facet of the `Intent` (which only works with one `Uri`). Try using `EXTRA_STREAM` as the `Intent` extra name, instead of your custom one. "Also, could you pass these flags endlessly to a next intent? Cuz there is a flow where the intent gets passed around to 2 activities before it gets read" -- ideally, you would have just the one activity and use fragments or something from there. But, any activity that has permissions can pass those along to the next activity.

Comment: In the end I see why you said it was not ideal... a lot of hassle and unclean code to make this work. I ended up with the intent-filters on the activity that handles the Uri's and worked my way from there. Wanted to say your link/website really helped me out!

Comment: Why am I getting this error @CommonsWare while my App has READ and WRITE PERMISSION. This error appears in some devices. When a user shares an Image from Gallery and I pass the Uri to the service for uploading!...

Comment: @Xenolion: Um, this appears to be covered by the answer and the blog post, though [I have written a newer version of the post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/08/08/uri-access-lifetime-still-shorter-than-you-might-think.html) since I wrote this answer. Beyond that, you might consider asking a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide a [mcve] showing how you "pass the Uri to the service".

Comment: The answer was not helpful for me to understand. But the link to the blog post to your website saved me. You should consider adding an upvote button there. @CommonsWare